# Difference between Angular service injection and importing object literals

Tags: angular, typescript

I think of services as of a file or files with those functionalities that are useful and commun to many components. So ultimately making those functionalities central and thus using in all those components.

What is special about these services that they have to be injected while I could create an object literal with the functionalities and just import them within components?

I can still call those functionalities using the object I imported?

Comment: services are singletons, objects are not.  If one component changes the value of a property of a service, other components can see that value changed, whereas if a component changes the value of a property on an object it imported, only it can see that change.

Comment: Injector allows to reinstantiate, replace or modify service instances without changing files where they are defined or used, including tests. This is not possible with imports, at least without hacks. This is a trait of any DI container and isn't specific to Angular.

Comment: Thanks guys, i think all the answers makes things more clear :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Imorting a class type and just using it is perfectly valid. However, the dependency injection mechanisms in Angular allow you to achieve the same thing, but with some added benefits:

- Instances can be singletons that can be scoped depending on where
  they are declared (app, module, component)
- You can declare a base class or interface (via an injection token) in your @Inject constructor parameter, and then configure which class will be injected in your module config
- The angular injector comes with a lot flexibility on how class instances are built-up and delivered by the injector
- You can inject different classes for testing than for runtime, which makes mocking test services very easy

Answer (score -1):

To restate what the comments say, a single instance of a service is intended to be used across multiple components/classes. This is what is done with dependency injection. For example if you had an array of to-do items in a service which was used by multiple components this list would be the same across all components, so if one component added to the list all of the other components would see this change reflected.

Importing an object literal, on the other hand, uses different instances for each component. So in the same example if the service **object** had an array of to-do items each component that imported this object would have a separate list of to-do items that would in no way relate to each other.

Hopefully that clarifies the issue.

Comment: It has to do with app composition, using modules vs using classes + DI tokens, but both provide the capability to trivially share state.

Comment: @Vega Isn’t he describing a Singleton?